# Batch file timed reminder

Tags: batch-file, time, reminders

I'm trying to get a .bat file to run a reminder popup do to restrictions on my work PC (Windows 7 OS). I am unable to use windows task scheduler due to these restrictions so I need the time check to run inside the batch file itself.

Currently, I have the following:

```
@echo off
:check
if "%time%"=="09:51:00.00"
msg user42 Test Reminder
Timeout /t 20 /nobreak
GOTO :Check
```

The issue seems to be with the "if" in the third line. as the rest of the code works with this line removed.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: `if` syntax: `if value1 comparator value2 command`. You need the command at the same line.

Comment: Do you really expect your loop to catch the time in centiseconds precision? Does your `%time%` really provide leading zero for hours < 10?

Comment: `%time%` has the format `09:51:00,00`, with a comma, not a dot. It should be `if "%time%" == "09:51:00,00" (msg user42 Test Reminder)` which is the correct syntax for `if` (and where the parentheses are optional).

Comment: besides what @Stephan mentioned above, additionally, do you expect your script to run every 20 seconds and eventually land exactly on `9:51:00,00` you realise your script will miss it 10 times out 0f 10..

Comment: @double-beep, the exact format returned by `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` depends on the regional settings, so it contains a `,` in German regions and a `.` in English ones, for instance...

Comment: Let me suggest to read the help of [`if /?`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) to learn the correct syntax; you should already have done that before asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need to manipulate your time variable to make this work as expected, but we don't really want to modify system or user environment variables. So we create our own.

First we make sure the time hour value always has 2 digits by replacing whitespace with `0` as only single digit time (1,2,3..9) will have a leading space. then we remove the `:` to make it a single matchable numeric value, then we simply do a match to see if the time is greater than or equal to 0951 (09:51 am) and if it is, we check if it is less than 0952 (09:52 am) meaning time has to be 09:51 any second and not 09:52 or larger.

Now we run the script every 50 seconds which will fall inside of each minute regardless, if we left it at 20 seconds, it would alert 2 or 3 times.

```
@echo off
:check
set mytime=%time: =0%
set mytime=%mytime::=%
if "%mytime:~0,4%" GEQ "0951" if "%mytime:~0,4%" LSS "0952" msg user42 Test Reminder
Timeout /t 50 /nobreak>nul
GOTO :Check
```

Comment: You force `if` to compare strings anyhow (and you need to do so because of the leading zero, which would indicate an octal number), so there is no need to remove the colon.

Comment: @stephan. True, somehow I just prefer to remove it. :)